# Old movie or tv show about man living longer which splits mankind

Tags: story-identification

The story is about the discovery of a kind of vaccine that permits the people to live longer. But some people react against the vaccine and become very strong and hostile (like hulk). The people that do not react to the vaccine live in a emerald or crystal city which is protected and isolated, and they are trying on searching the cure for this inconvenience. A hostile guy lives in the city and his pain level is super high.

There are also people who chose not to take the vaccine so they could live a regular life.

I saw this on tv many years ago.

Comment: Distantly reminds me of the [fourth Torchwood season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchwood:_Miracle_Day) or possibly [Aeon Flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeon_Flux_(disambiguation)).

Comment: The cheesy Doom movie had a story like this. Well, at least they tried to put in a "story" :)

Comment: possible duplicate (though this post is earlier) of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/old-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction/60509#60509

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are describing the movie Island city.

> In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate into a barbaric proto-humanoid state. The few people immune to this side-effect of the drug band together and live in a futuristic city while the mutants live in the vast wasteland outside its gates. In an effort to save the human race and understand what went wrong, the city sends out research missions in fortified vehicles to bring back mutated humans for research, and the film focuses specifically on one such squad of soldiers and scientists.

[Wikipedia Island City Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_%28film%29)

[IMDB Description](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110163/)