# Post-apocalypse scifi series with two human classes

Tags: story-identification, tv, post-apocalyptic

I remember watching a scifi series when I was growing up - it was either in the late 80s or early 90s that I watched it.  These are elements I can recall

1. The world was polluted or contaminated somehow
2. There were humans living in communities of a sort that had a higher level of technology that had cleaner air
3. The humans out in the polluted areas were more *Mad Max*-like and I think were mutated somehow or other
4. The 2 human elements were not friendly towards each other and there was a fair bit of conflict between them
5. Some of the cast for the humans in the community were more militarized and would go out to try and help people or to do repairs and such
6. I think that the terrain was more desert like for the most case

I don't remember much beyond these aside from the fact that I enjoyed the show.  Does anybody recall the name of this show?  I think that it was more serious than comedy, but I'm remembering from a child's perspective.

Comment: Possibly [*The Stand*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stand_(miniseries)): biological apocalypse, two groups who dislike each other, at least one character was (occasionally) mutated, parts of it take place in Nevada, one group was more benevolent. Except the 1994 airdate kind of pushes your timeframe

Comment: who was mutated in The Stand?

Answer (score 4):

This may have been the pilot for a series that never aired, called "Island City". The show featured a team that lived in the nice, climate-controlled city, yet often went out into the surrounding wasteland to help others and/or police the savages.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(film)):

> In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as
>   many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate
>   into a barbaric proto-humanoid state. The few people immune to this
>   side-effect of the drug band together and live in a futuristic city
>   while the mutants live in the vast wasteland outside its gates.

Thanks to the wonders of Youtube, here's the intro.

:

The show had some popular 90's actors in it but never took off. It was the answer to [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60488/20557) a while back, but in that case the OP was looking for it because of the color-coded crystals the city-dwellers wore to indicate genetic compatibility.

Comment: This was the one I was trying to remember. thanks! :) For the others that gave their input, I appreciate the help. It was Island city I was trying to remember though.  I hadn't realized it was a pilot, I remember seeing a few episodes, but that may just have been it being broken up into a few parts.

Comment: Glad to help @JeffS. - when you get a chance, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark icon under the voting buttons. Accepting an answer helps others to find it when searching for the same show/question. It also gives me sweet, glorious rep points :-P

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be [Genesis II(1973)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film)), [Planet Earth(1974)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(film)) or [Strange New World(1975)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_New_World_(TV_program)), three different tv pilots based on the same concept by Gene Roddenberry (although he wasn't directly involved in the third attempt).

A man, or group of people who were cryogenicly frozen before a catastrophic world war is found and revived by people from a city or organisation called PAX. These people , who still has access to technology, are trying to return some semblance of order to this post apocalyptic world.

And yes there are mutants.

A lot of the concepts from these pilots later went into the show Andromeda.