# 80s or 90s movie, caste system, colored crystals, desert, military vehicles

Tags: story-identification, movie, hard-sci-fi

Ok, this is vague yet vivid for me. An 80s or 90s film with people that either have a colored crystal (blue, yellow, and maybe red or purple,) that I believe determines what "class" they are. I think they are engineered. I remember one scene they are going through a desert in a sand storm, riding in military transport style vehicles with 6-8 wheels.  The crystals I think are on the back of their hands or on their foreheads, and may affect their eye color.  This is NOT DUNE.  I believe someone that may look like Patrick Swayze was in it. The plot isn't clear to me. Not much to go by, but thanks...

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/old-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction

Answer (score 8):

In the 1994 film [*Island City*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(1994_film)),

> Citizens of the city wore a colored crystal on their sternum and could only mate with other citizens of the same color, which was based on the individual's genetic makeup.

The city is surrounded by a desert-like wasteland, and [the opening credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2joNIuEE9zk) include an eight-wheeled armored vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

Could be a bit of a long shot, but this sounds like it might be [Logan's Run](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/synopsis).  Released in 1976, although perhaps you saw it on TV or home video in the 80s/90s.

After surviving a global conflict, the survivors of humanity live in a controlled environment, and are not allowed to live beyond 30 years.  At age 30 they are taken to be "reincarnated" (spoiler alert: they're just killed.)

Each person has a crystal implanted in their hand at birth, which starts off white and changes colours as they grow older.  IIRC, it turns red when it's time to go get "reincarnated."

[Here's a picture](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/mediaviewer/rm2453326848) of Logan (Michael York.)  I dunno how much he looks like Patrick Swayze, but maybe the mists of time took their toll?  (Note: I tried to upload the image directly, but SE said it was too big.)

I don't recall any deserts or military vehicles myself, although it has been a long time since I watched the movie.  There was, however, also a TV show that featured some scrubby terrain and [these things](http://www.virtualvikki.com/a/loganpics/tv/4more/cap7b.JPG).  (Again, can't upload the image... I'm wondering if there's a plugin in my browser that's messing with my ability to use the site...)