# TV show set in the future after humanity evolved?

Tags: story-identification, tv, future

I'm trying to remember a TV show that I watched years ago and wanted to show to someone else.  What I sort of remember is they are teenagers.  There is a quasi military structure to it all.  They had been in some sort of cryo sleep.  They were in some kind of compound surrounded in the woods by a large wall to keep out some creatures that seem to turn out to be what humanity evolved into.  There were several who wanted to not be involved with all this, hence the conflict of the show.

I wish I had more to go on right now.  Maybe others chime in with bits I might be able to remember more.

Comment: It bears some similarities to The 100 but there are enough differences that I don't think that's the answer.

Comment: This "teenagers stuck in a forest glade while the world gets dangerous" must be a trope because it sounds a bit like "The Maze Runner", except that's a film, not a TV show, and the "grievers" outside the wall are humanity's creation. The two sequels cover some people becoming "monsters" due to a mind plague (but still people-shaped), but I don't think it's close enough to be what you're thinking of.

Comment: [*Island City*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/90s-or-earlier-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction) also kind of fits, except they're not surrounded by woods.

Comment: All of those are good suggestions.  Yeah sounds like a trope and maybe resemble 100, but not.  Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This would be *[Wayward Pines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayward_Pines)* - a series about a mysterious town in the Pacific Northwest that turns out to be in the far future after most of humanity is extinct and "abbies" - monstrous descendants of humanity - roam outside the walls around the town. Teenagers in the town attend a school that indoctrinates them to follow the town's founder.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it.  Wayward Pines has teenagers in it but they aren't the focus.

Comment: Could be, though I think the teens were important enough that someone might remember them as the focus

Comment: Teenagers were the focus starting in the second season with that rebellion plot. It's very heavy especially in the first few episodes. It eases off later, but someone could remember it based on that.

Comment: Yes that's the case.  I was remembering the second season mostly.  Totally forgot about the adults until I checked it on imdb and recognized faces.  So definitely 100% Wayward Pines FTW :)

Answer (score 5):

It could be **[The 100](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2661044/)** that you're thinking about. The description fits much of season 1, except for the Cryo Sleep part:  they did spend a long time away from Earth and then returned, but they weren't in Cryo sleep while away.

- The series is centered around a large group of teenagers, with about a dozen main characters.
- They self-organize into a "military structure" with leaders, guard patrol teams, etc.
- They live in the woods and construct walls/barricades for defense.
- They encounter the local inhabitants, which turn out to be humans who stayed on earth. Depending on the intended meaning of "evolved", there's not much biological change but societies and lifestyles have changed during the time they were away.
- Some of them refuse to cooperate with the leadership, or just fight in between themselves, and there is constant conflict within the group.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2661044/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This was noted in a comment and discarded as not a match.  Can you make a good case that *The 100* matches the question, which does _not_ mention a space station, _does_ mention cryosleep and indicates that the remnants of humanity that were left behind have _evolved_ since the teens entered cryosleep?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks. I filled in the answer with more information on how I see it fits the question to a large degree. I've seen many answers on SO which started as comments and later were accepted. Also, questions in this genre are by their nature not usually exact, people don't remember all the details, or they get them mixed up with other stories, etc, so I don't see it as impossible because of the non-matching cryo sleep, and not mentioning space station. Not saying it has to be the 100, but it is a candidate.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion on both sides.  TBH I never saw the 100...think I had a different impression of it.  While this wasn't what I was looking for (Wayward Pines) from above, it is giving me another gem to discover :)

Answer (score 2):

It relates to one episode [S01E06 of Stagate Atlantis](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s1/childhoods-end/) "Childhood’s End".

- children live in tribes in the forest
- they organize not to be attacked by the Wraith (villain humanoid race)
- politics: some are questioning the death ritual to prevent adulthood

But it differs because of:

- it is not clear how the children arrived at this place (no cryo sleep)
- no wall to keep the bad guys out (they are protected by some technology)

Answer (score 1):

I have my doubts on it being a proper match, but a partial match is the 1994 film/pilot episode, *[Island City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(1994_film))*.

> In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate into a barbaric proto-humanoid state. The few people immune to this side-effect of the drug band together and live in a futuristic city while the mutants live in the vast wasteland outside its gates. In an effort to save the human race and understand what went wrong, the city sends out research missions in fortified vehicles to bring back mutated humans for research, and to rescue healthy humans. The film focuses on one such squad of soldiers and scientists.

It involves a future with an altered humanity outside of the protected area. There is a military structure, with several of the leads functioning in a fighting capacity. Due to the "Fountain of Youth" drug, the characters all appear young, although some are supposed to be older. Not matching is that the transformation of humanity is due to a combination of the drug and genetics (with one of the side plots being that reproduction is decided by lights in the chest of the citizens, to avoid a genetic combination that would lead to proto-humanoid progeny), the city is surrounded by something more akin to desert land than a forest, and I don't recall cryosleep factoring into it.

[image: A shot showing the city in the midst of the wastelands]

### Opening Credits

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but thank you for another idea to check out.  You guys on here are awesome :)