Post-apocalyptic movie from the 1980's; mutants live in a wasteland and are assigned color-codes that dictate who they can mate with
I saw a movie on TV, probably in the early 1980's about a post-apocalyptic society whose members explored the wastelands in some sort of high-tech RV/battlewagon and had occasional run-ins with mutants. Due to chromosome damage people were tested and assigned classifications identified by color (badge or watch?). While all types could freely associate in social settings, sex between different classifications was taboo. Blues went with blues, reds with reds, etc.
Sitting alone off to the side was this Cro-Magnon-looking guy whose mother had been raped by a mutant and as a result they had to create a new class just for him - black. He would never be allowed to mate.
Alone in a crowd at the end of the movie, a half-mutant girl from another colony approached his table. She too had been slotted black.
Anybody know the name?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/90s-or-earlier-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction and its linked answers go a bit further into detail about the lights in the chest indicating genetic compatibility, including mentioning one of the team members being kidnapped by the proto-humanoids (and that one of the proto-humanoids serves in their military, being an oddly intelligent example).

If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

This is definitely the 1994 pilot Island City (also released as Future City)


In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate into a barbaric proto-humanoid state. The few people immune to this side-effect of the drug band together and live in a futuristic city while the mutants live in the vast wasteland outside its gates. In an effort to save the human race and understand what went wrong, the city sends out research missions in fortified vehicles to bring back mutated humans for research, and to rescue healthy humans. The film focuses on one such squad of soldiers and scientists.

The black crystal is mentioned in this IMDB review, and is indeed on Lt. Michael Mendi, the "half recessed" soldier.

As for technological side, the jewels which everyone is forced to wear, by law in the show, shows how far the world may have to go in order to protect itself from disease. Basically the jewels are surgically implanted in each individual to show genetic compatibility in mates so as not to reproduce a devolved specimen of man. Apparently the life extension drug has screwed up everyone's DNA so only the right combinations of compatible mates are allowed to have children. Reds with reds, blues with blues, and so on and so forth. The only people who arn't allowed to procreate are those people who have a black jewel. Forbidden to procreate. Of course we only have one individual in the show who has a black jewel, and of course he's half devolved. Of course since most technologies we see in today's world is technology we see in scifi shows, who is to say these jewels won't be seen in the future to label people with diseases such as AIDS.

A review here mentions the clunky vehicles.

The future people have big chunky vehicles that look like absolute ass. Pretty sure they are pickups with a dopey louvered nose grafted on. There are miniature versions with serious issues in a few shots.


I just did a quick watch of the end of the pilot (not hard to find on YouTube) and the woman rescued has a green crystal once tested, which is the last color before black, and matches Gregg 23, a cloned "super soldier".


I'm assuming that Eric McCormack is the "super soldier", not the guy with the chiseled jawline, eyebrows that could cut glass, and hair you could use as a trampoline. ;)

@bob1 Yes. :) Peter Koch played the "half-recessive" Lt. Mendi. Who is the one who has a black crystal in his chest indicating that he cannot reproduce with anyone.

@FuzzyBoots That certainly sounds like the movie, although I thought it was older. Thanks for such a complete answer.

@Terry You're welcome. As you may see this one crops up often in memories. You can formally accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the tour.
