80’s to 90’s sci-fi film with humans aboard a spaceship, whose dating choices are determined by the emblems on their uniforms
Humans were aboard a spaceship. They performed their duties during the day and then paired up in the evenings according to emblems on and colors of their uniforms matching. People “dating” by their symbols matching on their uniforms caused minor grievances as some wanted to date up to someone more attractive but could not because of emblem patch differences.
Watched it late one night. Nice cinematography and color. Nice looking people and slight humor. Did not see anything else about it after that.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/90s-or-earlier-scifi-movie-glowing-lights-in-chests-to-indicate-attraction ?
